# How to find all child nodes of a node in puppeteer

Tags: node.js, selenium, xpath, web-crawler, puppeteer

Is there any way in puppeteer to find all child nodes of a node. In Java Selenium WebDriver we can find all child elements of a WebElement as shown here:

```
WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("..."));
List<WebElement> children = parent.findElements(By.tagName("div"));
```

Now is there any similar methods in puppeteer to fetch child elements like this. If i'm fetching parent element/node like this

```
var parent = await page.$x('//*[@class="myClass"]');
```

The problem is the above line of code returns list of nodes, now i have to find child nodes of each node in parent array.

for example:

```
var child = parent[0].childrens;
```

Something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the child elements of element located by `//*[@class="myClass"]` XPath you can simply do this:

```
var children = await page.$x('//*[@class="myClass"]//*');
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, what if //*[@class="myClass"] xpath returns list of elements/nodes and i have to find child nodes of each node in the "parent" array/list

Comment: This still will work properly. This will return a list of all those parent elements